# rewrite sql without with clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, with-clause

I've fallen down the SQL rabit hole, please help me
I need to rewrite this query without the with clause

```
with dept_total(dept_name, value) as
     (select dept_name, sum(salary)
     from instructor
     group by dept_name),
dept_total_avg(value) as 
     (select avg(value)
     from dept_total)
select dept_name
from dept_total, dept_total_avg
where dept_total.value >= dept_total_avg.value;
```

basically the first table adds up all salaries based on department. the second table gets an average of the sums. I need to find a way to pick out the departments that have a department total greater than the averages.

It can be written any way as long as it doesn't use the with clause. I've been thinking about - 
select sum(salary)/count(salary) as dept_total_avg, dept_name
from instructor
where dept_total_avg > all (select sum(salary),
                           from instructor)
group by dept_name;

but it doesn't work and now my brain doesn't either. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the department average without access to the intermediate cte `dept_total`

```
SELECT
    dept_total.dept_name, dept_total.value, cj.dept_av
FROM (
    SELECT
        dept_name, SUM(salary) value
    FROM instructor
    GROUP BY
        dept_name
    ) AS dept_total
CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT
            SUM(salary) / (COUNT(DISTINCT dept_name) * 1.0) dept_av
        FROM instructor
    ) cj
WHERE dept_total.value >= cj.dept_av
;
```

In the original query there are 2 "common table expressions" (cte) and each one is given a name so that they can be referred to later.

The first of these is given the name `dept_total`

Any following cte is allowed to reuse that cte by that name. However this reuse aspect of cte's is not possible with traditional "derived table" subqueries. Hence where the name `dept_total` is used in the final query you have to substitute a new way to arrive at the departmental average.

---

In case you are not aware, MySQL 8 is now available and it supports "common table expressions" (the `with clause`)