# Transferring SQL query from with clause to without with clause

Tags: sql, database, with-statement

Consider the query:

Find all departments where the total salary is greater than the average of the total salary at all departments

```
with dept_total (dept_name, value) as
(
    select dept_name, sum(salary)
    from instructor
    group by dept_name
),
dept_total_avg(value) as
(
    select avg(value)
    from dept_total
)
select dept_name
from dept_total, dept_total_avg
where dept_total.value >= dept_total avg.value;
```

Rewrite this query without using the with construct.

The query is based on University schema which is provided by The database system concept by Korth. I assume I need to consider only the instructor table to find the answer of the query.

Instructor (**ID**, name, dept_name, salary)

I can found the average of total salary of all dept

```
SELECT AVG(salary) GROUP BY dept_name;
```

Then I lost. I did not find the way to proceed.

I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111096/rewrite-sql-without-with-clause). But I am looking for more explanation as I cannot understand it from this link.

Thank you for help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few ways to do it in a mySQL version that doesn't support CTEs (I'm assuming that's why they are having you rewrite the query to omit the with).  Also, you are calculating the average salary by department, but the question is asking to find the average TOTAL salary of each department, then return the ones that fall above that.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=fefea829cff3e20aea93634f9a4114d6

With a subquery:

```
SELECT dept_name
FROM (
  SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as salaries
  FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
) d

WHERE salaries > (
  SELECT avg(salaries) as avgSalaries FROM (
    SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as salaries
    FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
  ) z
)
```

With a join:

```
SELECT dept_name
FROM (
  SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as salaries
  FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
) d
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT avg(salaries) as avgSalaries FROM (
    SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as salaries
    FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
  ) z
) avgs
WHERE salaries > avgs.avgSalaries
```

With a session variable (this is deprecated in later versions, but does still work):

```
SELECT avg(salaries) INTO @avg FROM (
  SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as salaries
  FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
) z;

SELECT @avg;

SELECT dept_name
FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name
HAVING sum(salary) > @avg;
```

All good techniques to understand.

Comment: I'd go with INNER JOIN ... ON, instead of CROSS JOIN ... WHERE.

Comment: Me too, probably.  I think they'll probably come out the same in the optimizer, but I think what I was trying to highlight is that since you're joining to a result set with one row the join condition doesn't matter so much and I was using the result just as a comparator.  Probably should have just said that instead of writing it like that.  I am not sure when the last time I actually used a cross join was.

Comment: With subquery solution what is d and z represent?

Comment: In mySQL every derived table needs an alias, so d and z are just aliases for the nested select statements.   If you want to select from a nested select, you have to give it a name.   These were just convenient.  I picked d for the first because it was the first letter of dept_name and z for the other because generally I start with z and work backwards through the alphabet if I don't know right off hand how many levels I'll be nesting.  d and z could be anything right here.  You could use any alias at all.

Answer (score 0):

Read your last question and found that you are using mysql5.8, then you can use the analysis function

```sql
select distinct t1.dept_name
  from (
select t1.*,
       sum(salary) over(partition by dept_name) val,
       sum(salary) over() / count(distinct dept_name) over() avg
  from Instructor t1
) t1
 where t1.val > t1.avg
```